# How to hide a question from my profile (even temporary)?

Tags: support, profile-page

I would like to know if there is any way in which I could:

- Hide a question from my profile TOP POST page (even temporary).
- Or in some how change its position from TOP POST page.

I am asking this as In few occasion I was invited from some HR agencies to send my profile page for quick review. In few occasion they had express some concerns regarding this question:

[Make first letter of a string upper case (for maximum performance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4135317/make-first-letter-of-a-string-upper-case-for-maximum-performance)

I understand at first glance seems a very NEW an trivial question.

When in fact is a question from 2010, in which I was interested in a performance issue.

The question actually received several up-votes and bookmarked more that ten times. Still I had a strong feeling that was not helping me in the HR process.

I would be not happy to delete permanently that question as could be still of interest.

Any opinions is also very welcome. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Why does that specific question create problems for you with HR agencies interested in you?

Comment: I am concerning regarding creating a reasonable image, I had a feeling that question was not welcome in several occasions. To me it seems like the HR  person did not have time to read (and look at the date) of that question properly.

Comment: HR shouldn't be making decisions based on technical material; that's not their expertise. I suspect they forwarded your profile info to someone in a technical position who then gave them feedback; if not, I would be wary of working somewhere with an HR department like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First and foremost, **no**, there is not a way to hide a specific question from your profile. At least, not currently. You could put in a feature request over on [Meta Stack Exchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Secondly, I don't believe that asking a good, well-received question would hurt anyone professionally. Programming is, by definition, an exercise in logic. There will always be more than one way to accomplish a task. Because of that fact, there may always be a better way to solve a problem.

As someone who has been on a few hiring committees for technical positions, I personally would not hold that question against you. No one person knows everything and what you have shown is you have the knowledge and the abilities to find answers to problems you face, even when you don't know how to approach them initially.

There is no shame in asking for help. It shows your willingness to learn and grow. And the community has affirmed that by providing upvotes, favoriting the question, and contributing quality answers.